# Форматирование вещественных (float) данных в DataFrame при выводе на экран

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

выгружаю данные из эксель таблицы (форматы всех столбцов одинаковы!)
Но в DF отображаются по-разному, некоторые столбцы нормально, а некоторые в стиле `2.113000e+02`. Когда выгружаешь в Excel все хорошо, но пока работаешь именно такой формат. Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [65]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[123.45678, 1.23456789e10, 1.23456789e-12]})

In [66]: df
Out[66]:
              a
0  1.234568e+02
1  1.234568e+10
2  1.234568e-12

In [67]: pd.set_option('display.float_format', '{:.3f}'.format)

In [68]: df
Out[68]:
                a
0         123.457
1 12345678900.000
2           0.000
```